# GRASP - information expert pattern - approach

Tags: java, design-patterns, modeling, grasp

I'm looking for **best-practice approach** in the following case. I have three Java classes: `ManualComponent`, `AutomaticComponent` and `CustomComponent`, which extend abstract class `CalculationComponent` and implement the following `CalculableComponent` interface:

```
public interface CalculableComponent {
    void calculate();
}
```

There's another class which aggregates those `CalculationComponent` in `ComponentBox`:

```
public class ComponentBox {
    private Set<CalculationComponent> components;

    public void calculateAll() {
        for (CalculationComponent c : components) {
            c.calculate();
        }
    }
}
```

Everythig worked perfect till I was asked to change the implementation of `calculate()` method in `CustomComponent`. Currently, this method **needs information from other** already-calculated `CalculationComponents` (=information from `Set<CalculationComponent> components` located in `ComponentBox` like this `calculate(components);`).

My understanding of GRASP is that `ComponentBox` class is now **Information Expert**, because now it contains all information needed to make final calculation (`calculateAll();`).

How should I change my classes in order to get best-practice approach?

Thank You for your help!
M.

Comment: Information expert is about putting a method in the right class, that is, the one that has the information to fulfill the responsibility. I think your calculate methods are ok, but the problem you are having is one of access to information (it is not accessible because of the abstractions)? Can you provide a concrete case of what is not working?